# Time out. bytes not found : what type of error is this?

Tags: windows

This errors happens with Movavi Video Converter, when I open software I get this error

```
Time out. bytes not found
```

To bypass refresh files where is located Movavi .exe and delete temporally files from AppData and ProgramData, then software open successfully but not always
But why happens ? What make this error, is a compilation exception ?

[image: error]

Comment: Did you try googling the error? https://www.google.com/#safe=strict&q=bytes+not+found Seems like multiple people have this issue, might want to start there...

Comment: I wish to understand not why movavi has this problem, but in programming reference what should be this error caused ?

Comment: This is an error on the part of the programmers. It has nothing to do with compilation of the program nor is it likely to be a problem with your system. The programmers decided that rather than handle a condition properly they spew out this completely unhelpful error box and leave you to deal with it. Find a better media converter.

Comment: ok Mokubai, what is the cause in programming of this error box ? A function implemented badly ?

Comment: I'm no programming expert, but this looks like a generic error inserted by the developer, not an error generated by the code/compiler itself. (As Mokubai said above) So there's really no way of knowing what caused it.

Comment: mm.. but string error is indifferent ? I read 'Time out'. What do you mean ?